# Prevent REF errors without using INDIRECT?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

So it's well known that an INDIRECT function can prevent formulas from breaking if a sheet is deleted:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!A1")
```

Even if Sheet2 is deleted and replaced later, the formula will remain (whereas if we just had `Sheet2!A1` it would otherwise break and become `=#REF!A1`. The sheet could also have its cells cleared (values replaced only) to prevent breaking, but this question is specifically about the case where sheets are deleted.

Is there another way to prevent formulas from breaking in this situation? INDIRECT is sort of slow since it has to recalculate everything - is there an alternative that somehow preserves these formulas even when the sheet is deleted and later replaced?

Comment: I used an if() with a cell to say on or off.

Comment: Maybe the question is why you delete tabs that you want to keep using. Can't you overwrite the values instead? That way you can avoid the use of the volatile INDIRECT function